# Probability that the product of the numbers on two dice is at least $18$ if at least one of the numbers is divisible by $3$

Tags: probability

I'm getting ready for a test. I have one example, and I need you to verify if I understand it correctly. So the exercise is like this:

$2$ dice thrown once.

> a) What is the probability that fallen numbers have a product greater than $15$?

My solution: $11/36$ -> all possibilities are $36$ and $11$ are good

> b) What is the probability that fallen numbers has a product greater than $18$, if on second die the fallen number is divisible by $3$

My solution: $3/36$ -> the second die has only $2$ options (3,6) and the first die has $3$ (6,4,5)

> c)  What is the probability that fallen numbers have a product greater then $18$, if either the first or second fallen number is divisible by $3$

This I don't know.

Can you check if a and b is correct, and can I get a little help with c?

Thanks.

Comment: $a$ and $b$ look good.  Your method works fine for $c$ as well, stick with it.  List all the good cases.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: @lulu  Are you sure?  If the second die is $3$ or $6$ there are not $36$ outcomes but only $12$.

Answer (score 2):

b) is incorrect.

We are told that the second die must be divisible by three.  So that is $2$ and not $6$ options so there are only $6*2 =12$ options and the probability is $\frac 3{12} = \frac 14$.

This is known as conditional probability.

To give new user MathTest his/her due:

S/he posted [Reply to one of the exercises here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2902980/reply-to-one-of-the-excerises-here#2902980)

> I cannot post on the already created topic, but I think I found a
>   mistake and I want to clarify it. So the example is this:
>
> ```
> 2 dice thrown once.
>
> b) what is the probability that fallen numbers has a product greater then 18, if on second dice the fallen number is divided by 3
>
> My solution: 3/36 -> the second dice has only 2 options(3,6) and the first dice has 3 (6,4,5)
> ```
>
> Are you sure this is correct ?
>
> So all possibilities that the product is greater then 18 is 12. But
>   the correct one are only 3 (that meets the condition that the second
>   dice has a number that is divided by 3 ).
>
> So I get: (3/36) / (12/36)
>
> and me solution is 1/4. Which is correct ?

And the answer is s/he is.